# Illegal char <:> at index 38: \\install.domain.com\updates$\Oracle;C:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\ojdbc.properties

Tags: oracle, windows-10, oracle-sqldeveloper, ojdbc

How to resolve Illegal char <:> at index 38: \install.domain.com\updates$\Oracle;C:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\ojdbc.properties
error connecting in Oracle SQL developer

[Connection credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVNdo.jpg)

Exception stack trace:

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 38: \\install.onsemi.com\updates$\Oracle;C:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin\ojdbc.properties
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PropertiesFileUtil.validatePath(PropertiesFileUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PropertiesFileUtil.loadDefaultFiles(PropertiesFileUtil.java:204)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PropertiesFileUtil.loadPropertiesFromFile(PropertiesFileUtil.java:137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getConnectionPropertiesFromFile(PhysicalConnection.java:9880)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.readConnectionProperties(PhysicalConnection.java:1042)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:739)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:38)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:704)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.AbstractConnectionCreator.getConnection(AbstractConnectionCreator.java:222)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnectionImpl(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:399)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.standalone.connection.RaptorConnectionCreator.getConnection(RaptorConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.dialogs.conn.ConnectionPrompt.promptForPassword(ConnectionPrompt.java:67)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.DatabaseProviderHelper$PasswordPrompter.promptForPassword(DatabaseProviderHelper.java:422)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.db.DBConnAddin$2.promptForPassword(DBConnAddin.java:89)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:377)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.adapter.DatabaseProvider.getConnection(DatabaseProvider.java:354)
    at oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.CAConnectionCreator.createConnectionImpl(CAConnectionCreator.java:51)
    at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createConnection(DatabaseFactory.java:838)
    at oracle.javatools.db.DatabaseFactory.createDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:282)
    at oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections.getDatabase(DatabaseConnections.java:657)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections$ConnectionInfo.getDatabase(Connections.java:287)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1183)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.utils.Connections.getConnection(Connections.java:1169)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:83)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.DatabaseConnection.openConnectionImpl(DatabaseConnection.java:38)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.BaseConnectionNode.getConnection(BaseConnectionNode.java:91)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode.getObjectFactory(DatabaseTreeNode.java:90)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:145)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.navigator.db.impl.DatabaseTreeNode$LoadTask.doWork(DatabaseTreeNode.java:119)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:199)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:702)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: apparently SQL Developer is complaining about a `:` in a Windows path. Any ideas?

Comment: version of SQLDev? In preferences, Database, Advanced, make sure the OCI / Thick config is legit. It's having problem loading the thick driver. So easiest answer is, go thin instead

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I also could not solve this when using a newer version of SQL Developer and had to revert to version 19.2.0.206 and do the following.

I had a very similar issue and thatjeffsmith's comment helped me narrow it down. In **Preferences > Database > Advanced** I had to check **Use Oracle Client** and specify the Oracle driver client folder:

[image]